# Blob's migration data from Informix to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, export, informix, database-migration

I am migrating Informix (11.7) DB to PostgreSQL(9.2). There is only one problem: how to move blob(image) from Informix to PostgreSQL(9.2)? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need the data type of postgres or do you have any specific problem? The data type you are looking for is bytea in postgres.

Comment: How are you migrating the non-blob data to PostgreSQL? What formats does PostgreSQL like for loading blob data?  How many tables with blobs are you migrating?  How many rows in those tables?  How big are the blobs (min, avg, max)? Which of the Informix types TEXT, BYTE, BLOB and CLOB are you dealing with?  They're all blob types.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: What are the specs for storing Informix TEXT, BYTE, BLOB and CLOB data?

Comment: What do you mean, @FrankComputer?  TEXT and BYTE blobs are older (version 4.00) than the other two types (version 9.00) and can be stored IN TABLE or in a blob space.  The BLOB and CLOB types are for 'smart blobs', and are stored in a smart blob space (different).  There are complicated rules about how to get the values into the DB and back out again.  There's a set of rules about how they're unloaded too if you're using UNLOAD format.  And so the list of unanswered questions grows...

Comment: What I mean is: Are any specs available which explain how these datatypes are internally stored, so that one can determine if they are portable from one db to another. How would these datatypes appear if one were to unload them to a flat text file, or if one were to retrieve them via ODBC?

Comment: @FrankComputer: They're stored internally in opaque formats that are obscure beyond belief. Large tranches of the disk space are simply the data, of course, but the control information is complex — and some is in the blob descriptor in the row of the table while some is in the blob space or smart blob space where the blob is stored (except when it is stored IN TABLE).  There's no external documentation (stuff you can see) on how to get at the raw blob data.

Comment: So, can Informix BLOB/CLOB's be externally accesed via ODBC? What is the best method for migrating them to another DB?

Answer (score 1):

I did some such conversions between various databases using Jython and JDBC.

All you need is Informix and PostgreSQL JDBC drivers in `CLASSPATH`.

I have Informix table with `BYTE` column, and PostgreSQL table with `BYTEA` column:

```
-- Informix
CREATE TABLE _blob_test (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  image BYTE
)

-- PostgreSQL
CREATE TABLE _blob_test (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  image BYTEA
)
```

Then you can use JDBC `getObject()/setObject()` methods to copy data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env jython
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

from java.sql import DriverManager
from java.lang import Class

Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver")
Class.forName('org.postgresql.Driver')

def copy_table(db_from, db_to):
    col_count = 2
    insert_stmt = db_to.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO _blob_test (id, image) VALUES (?, ?)')
    pstm2 = db_from.createStatement()
    pstm2.setFetchSize(10000)
    rs_in = pstm2.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM _blob_test')
    try:
        batch_buffer = 0
        batch_size = 100
        while (rs_in.next()):
            for i in range(1, col_count + 1):
                insert_stmt.setObject(i, rs_in.getObject(i))
            insert_stmt.addBatch()
            batch_buffer += 1
            if (batch_buffer % batch_size == 0):
                insert_stmt.executeBatch()
                batch_buffer = 0
        if (batch_buffer > 0):
            insert_stmt.executeBatch()
    finally:
        rs_in.close()
        pstm2.close()


db_from = DriverManager.getConnection('jdbc:informix-sqli://informix-test:9088/infdb:informixserver=ol_testifx;DB_LOCALE=pl_PL.CP1250;CLIENT_LOCALE=pl_PL.CP1250;charSet=CP1250', 'informix', '12345')
db_to   = DriverManager.getConnection('jdbc:postgresql://pg-test:5490/pg_test?stringtype=unspecified', 'postgres', '12345')

copy_table(db_from, db_to)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is late but this could help other persons looking for a solution.
We have done a similar migration in our company.
To migrate binaries we used a tool called SQL-workbench, we used the data pumper (menu tools). Data pumper allows to copy data from a source DB to a target DB. The DBMSs could be different (in this case Informix and Postgres).
You have to register both drivers in "File > Manage Drivers" and create 2 profiles: A source profile targeting your Informix DB and a target profile targeting your Postgres DB. The profiles will then be selected from Data pumper.
[image: Data pumper window]
If you have several tables to copy at once, please read the documentation about using the function Wbcopy (very useful)