# Derby Database ODBC Connection

Tags: database, odbc, derby

I have a Derby Database in Netbeans with connection string

```
jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDatabase
```

Can this be used with ODBC? If so, how could I transform this or configure my Derby Database to be compliant with ODBC

The end goal is to get the Derby Database migrated to MySQL. Using the migrating wizard in MySQL Workbench appears to be the easiest way. However I do need ODBC connectivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to use ODBC because MySQL Workbench uses it to migrate database?

I migrated some databases between various engines and my favorite technology is to convert DDL schema (`CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE VIEW` etc) using specialized Python program. Then I use JDBC with `getObject()`/`setObject()` methods to copy data. You can see such copy database Jython program (Jython is a Python language that works using JVM and can use JDBC drivers) in my response to [Blob's migration data from Informix to Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997939/blobs-migration-data-from-informix-to-postgres/13026513#13026513) .

BTW Quick search shows that IBM have ODBC driver to Derby (they bought Informix that earlier bought Cloudscape): http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0409cline2/

Answer (score 1):

Use [OpenDBCopy](http://opendbcopy.sourceforge.net/), which is an opensource database utility to migrate data from and to any database via JDBC connection.

You can copy table structures as well as data from any supported database.