# PHP connect to apache derby

Tags: php, pdo, derby

```
$database='comdb';
$hostname='localhost';
$port=1527;
$user='root';
$password='pass';

$DSN = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};PROTOCOL=TCPIP;"
     . "DATABASE=$database;HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;"
     . "UID=$user;PWD=$password;";
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:$DSN");
```

i installed the DB2 ODBC driver and apply php_pdo_odbc.dll on php ext
and still i can't connect to derby error appear after i run the script

```
Failed to connect: SQLSTATE[08001] SQLDriverConnect: -30082 [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N Security processing failed with reason "17" ("UNSUPPORTED FUNCTION"). SQLSTATE=08001
```

please let me know if there is alternate way to connect to derby database.
i can access the database using SQuirrel SQL Client but i need to connect it using php.
thanks

Comment: `$database='comdb;` not closed quotation mark. and no ';` after $user and $password delcaration

Comment: I edit it now. and that should be the same as my script :P

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the DB2 ODBC driver can connect to the Derby Network Server. However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637844/derby-database-odbc-connection) has some ideas you could pursue.

Comment: do you have some simple or quick tuts on it?