# Python Database Connection String with Derby Database

Tags: python-2.7, database-connection, derby

Just to let you know about the problem i am facing, I will give a short introduction about what I have been doing.

I am working on a project, where the WEB interface is constructed in Java. 
There is a parser built in python, which parses data and stores it into the database.

We were using a MySQL server, but were later asked to change it into DERBY. The java code now works perfectly connecting with the database.

But the python part of the code has problems with connection. I learnt how the derby database works, but find it hard to find articles about connecting to a derby database.

I have the following details:

```
uname               : root
pwd                 : root
driver class        : org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
DRIVER LOCATIONS    : C:\Users\esusank\AppData\Roaming\RazorSQL\derby\derby10.10.jar    
JDBC URL            : jdbc:derby:C:\Derby\databases\MyDbTest;create=true
```

I am finding it hard to find syntax for writing a connection string for DERBY.

I have installed mxODBC driver.

Can someone help me out on this? If you can post some links or some suitable syntax, it will be very much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with Derby, you will need to use a JDBC driver. ODBC drivers can't talk directly to Derby; it is a Java-only database.

I believe there are some ODBC-JDBC bridge providers that provide such connection mechanisms, but I'm not sure if they are still in active use.

Another possibility is to use Jython, which is a Java implementation of Python, which may help: see this related question: [Derby Database ODBC Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637844/derby-database-odbc-connection)