# Protocol issue connecting Derby by db2 ODBC

Tags: db2, odbc, derby

This is a problem when I tried to connect Derby Database by DB2 ODBC

I started the Derby Network Server and created a database named "mydb"
but,after I did as the steps described in an article on IBM's site,I countered a problem on the server side.

Step 1->db2 catalog tcpip node MYDERBY remote localhost server 1527

Step 2->db2 catalog db mydb at node MYDERBY authentication server

Step 3->db2 connect to mydb user abc using abc

Problem:
Execution failed because of a Distributed Protocol error:DRDA_Proto_SYNTAXRM;
CODPNT arg=112e;error code value=14;Plaintext connection attempt from an SSL enabled client?

What can I do to accomplish or it is unworkable??

db2_v10.12_winx64_expc

db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin

Comment: Why do you use a DB2 ODBC driver to connect to a Derby database, which is JDBC-only by the way? Why not try Oracle or SQL Server driver?

Comment: Cause I try to use Derby database with C#,I just want to know if it is possible to use Derby in .NET environment.

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of the Derby Network Server do not communicate with the DB2 ODBC client, as far as I know. You might look here: http://apache-database.10148.n7.nabble.com/ODBC-Driver-for-Derby-td102587.html or here: http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-derby-driver/index.html#section=tab-1 or  here: [Derby Database ODBC Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637844/derby-database-odbc-connection?rq=1) for some more ideas.

Note: I gave a relatively similar answer to a relatively similar question here: [Derby Database ODBC Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637844/derby-database-odbc-connection?rq=1) and it was deleted, so for all I know this answer may be deleted as well.