# Fatal error: Call to undefined function db2_connect() using WAMP when trying to connect to Derby DB

Tags: php, derby

I hope someone can help me with this error. I know it pops up due to php not recognizing the php_ibm_db2.dll module, but I've tried everything and nothing works. I've looked for tutorials, but many of them are very old and refers to the old version of IBM products which makes it harder for me to understand.

Older similar questions posted here either goes unanswered or solved vaguely.

Here are the basics:

- System: Windows 7 Pro 64bit
- WAMP: 2.5 64bit (Apache is 2.4.9 & PHP is 5.5.12)
- Database: Derby, located in the same computer as WAMP/localhost

I needed to connect to the db using php and retrieve the data. I tried using odbc but I received 'Function Unsupported' with both IBM DB2 ODBC Driver and IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC, so I scrapped the idea and decided to go with db2 functions instead.

Here's what I've tried:

- Downloaded extension from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/db2mc/files/IBM_DB2%20PHP%20Driver%20for%20Windows/): I got the 5.5 ts version and copied the .dll into PHP's ext folder
- Added extension=php_ibm_db2.dll line in php.ini linked by WAMP
- Installed everything from [IBM download page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=4020&uid=swg27016878). It's stupid but I don't know what to do anymore
- Checked if PATH, .ini or .conf settings are not pointed to the correct folder*
- Restarted WAMP
- Restarted computer

*I previously configured PHP to include Firebird headers, so I know I modified the correct .conf & .ini. The PHP folder is also defined in the environment variables.

PHP error log contains the following:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ibm_db2.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

The code:

```
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "localhost";
$port = "1527";
$database="C:\Users\me\Desktop\dbname"; //not real definition

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;"."HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$username;PWD=$password";

$connection = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');
if ($connection) {
   echo "Connection succeeded."."\n";
}
else {
   echo "Connection failed."."\n";
   echo db2_conn_errormsg ($connection);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The location you say you downloaded the php_ibm_db2 extension from only has 32bit code _(x86)_. It wont run on a 64bit WAMPServer. Unless you can find a 64bit extension you will have to install the 32bit WAMPServer 2.5

Comment: That explains everything. I'l try setting up 32-bit WAMP in a virual machine and see.

Comment: See this related question, possibly a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/31353425/193453

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton I've read the linked articles. That's really a bummer. Are you really sure there's no way to access the data in Derby using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RiggsFolly and a question I failed to find again to link here, I figured it out now.

For anyone trying to enable db2 functions in Windows x64 and thinks [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ibm-db2.installation.php) installing guide is not very specific, here are the steps (or at least, what I used to solve it):

1. Install a 32-bit WAMPServer
2. Install [IBM Express-C x32](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express-c/download.html). This comes with the IBM DB2 ODBC Driver.
3. Download [php_ibm_db2.dll](http://sourceforge.net/projects/db2mc/files/IBM_DB2%20PHP%20Driver%20for%20Windows/) according to your PHP version. Copy into PHP extension folder and enable it in the PHP.ini
4. To configure the DSN for the x32 ODBC Driver, use the x32 ODBC Data Source Administrator in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe.
5. Restart WAMPServer and check PHPInfo(). ibm db2 should have it's own section now

I hope this will be useful to someone.

OR

just download a suitable version from [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/ibm_db2). I just discovered that and I feel super dumb.