# Informix SE to PostgreSQL data migration

Tags: postgresql, import, migration, export, informix

I'm rewriting an old application running on SCO Unix that connects to an Informix SE 7.24 database. The target os is RHEL 6.3 and the dbms is PostgreSQL 9.4.

I've already adapted the DDL script and created the empty database but now I'm looking for a way to migrate data. Informix and PostgreSQL are using two different character set, CP437 and UTF8.

I've tried to export the database with the *dbexport* utility, converted *.unl files to the new charset and then loaded with the `COPY table_name FROM 'table.unl' (DELIMITER '|', ENCODING 'UTF-8', NULL '')`. This worked for most of the tables but when the size of the .unl file grows (over 1GB), the import process crash. What can I do?

Comment: What error message you get when your import process "crashes"? `COPY` supports much larger data sets than 1GB, so I don't suppose that data size is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have not show us `COPY` error message.

I migrated some databases and one of the easiest way is to use JDBC especially with Jython (Python that works on JVM). You can see such migration in my response: [Blob's migration data from Informix to Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997939/blobs-migration-data-from-informix-to-postgres/13026513) Of course you must change it to use your schema, but with JDBC it is easy to read table names and other schema info.